# Why is .NET inconstent in calling directories "Directory" and "Folder"?

Tags: .net

If you want to do something with a directory/folder you use `System.IO.Directory` but if you want to display a dialog for browsing one you use `FolderBrowserDialog`?

Why is one named Directory and the other Folder?

Comment: "That which we call a rose by any other name would smell as sweet" (shakespeare), or more appropriately: "That which we call a directory by any other name would work just as well"

Comment: Possibly because "directory" is the low-level, file-system name and "folder" is what it's called in the UI? Just guessing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There actually is a difference between a directory and a folder, and both terms are used correctly here.

A directory is a file system concept.  The `System.IO.Directory` class, along with most of the classes in the `System.IO` namespace, deals only with the file system, ie. files, directories, and drives.  These are sometimes collectively referred to (programmatically or just grammatically) as file system objects, or FSOs.

A folder, on the other hand, is an operating system concept.  More specifically, it's a Windows shell concept.  It's a higher-level concept than a directory.  The Windows shell doesn't usually deal directly with file system objects.  Instead, everything is abstracted as *namespace objects*.  There are two types of namespace objects: *folders*, which are containers for other namespace objects, and *files*, which aren't.  (Note that a "file" in the namespace doesn't necessarily correlate to a file on disk.  It could be a virtual object, like a printer.)

Most namespace objects represent file system objects, but not all of them do.  For instance, the Desktop folder is a virtual folder that houses all of the file system objects in `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop%` as well as the file system objects in `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Desktop`, and a few non-file-system objects like the Recycle Bin, My Computer, etc.

Like Windows Explorer, the `FolderBrowserDialog` (which, as Benny almost mentioned, calls `SHBrowseForFolder()`) presents an abstract view of folders<sup>1</sup>, not a direct view of the drives and directories of the file system.

It should also be noted that the `System.IO.Directory` class is part of the ECMA-spec base class library (BCL), which is intended to be platform-agnostic.  Directories exist on virtually every platform.  The `System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog` class is not part of the BCL.  It's in the Windows-specific .NET framework, so its designers were free to use Windows concepts, such as the folder<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> On the other hand, the .NET framework doesn't actually support namespace objects.  Although the `SHBrowseForFolder()` function can return any namespace folder, the `FolderBrowserDialog` uses the `BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS` flag to restrict returns to only folders that represent file system directories.  You can't use the `FolderBrowserDialog` to allow the user to choose the Printers folder or the Control Panel folder.  Nonetheless, though, it does *browse* by folder, even if it will only retrieve the path to a directory.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> Most modern file browsers borrow the *metaphor* of folders, representing directories graphically with folder icons, but the abstract concept of folders, as presented here, is a Windows concept that isn't universally present across platforms.</sub>

Answer (score 14):

Probably because the team that wrote the `System.IO` namespace was not the same team that wrote `System.Windows.Forms`.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe because Folder in this case is rather a term of Windows(not only?) user interface than a definition of file system object.

Answer (score 3):

In the good ol' days of DOS, back in the 1980's, when DOS 2.0 came along and introduced the concept of putting files in more than one place on your 160K floppy disk or 10MB hard disk, Microsoft called these "directories", or "subdirectories" the original shell command being `DIR` to list said files.

When the first Windows 1.0 UI came along several years later, said directories were represented by a folder icon in the MS-DOS Executive, which is what the Windows Explorer was originally known as (more or less).

Hence, "folder" is a user-friendly metaphor for the more technical sounding "directory".

Comment: A similar metaphor existed on the Commodore Amiga, although they have chosen "Drawer" instead of "Folder".

Comment: And on top of that, Microsoft tried to add the briefcase concept to hold many folder, but that concept failed against the general public. +1 for historical reference

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because FolderBrowserDialog is a porting function from win32 platform SDK ShellBrowseForFolder()

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one was written by a Mac dude and the other by a PC dude.